# Javascript linking with window.open

Tags: javascript

I am trying to give a link from my php page. But its showing an error. Is the following script correct? Can anyone help me pls? Its an annotation problem. Some where i have not put the annotation correctly?

```
window.open('add_new_shipment.php?tender_id='+result["tender_id"]& 
    id='+result["id"], 'quotation', 'scrollbars=yes', 'menubar=no', 'status=no', 'width=800, height=600');
```

Comment: ]& BIIIIIIIIIIIIIP

Comment: Just by looking at the ` ' ` I see some red flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing `+ '` Plus sign and single quote

```
window.open('add_new_shipment.php?tender_id='+result["tender_id"] +'&id='+result["id"], 'quotation', 'scrollbars=yes', 'menubar=no', 'status=no', 'width=800, height=600');
                                                             ------^
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Its fine now.

Answer (score 0):

var result = 50;
var id = 4;

window.open('add_new_shipment.php?tender_id='+result+'&'+'id='+id+',quotation,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,status=no,width=800,height=600');
});

if you are using php in create url then use this script

window.open('add_new_shipment.php?tender_id=&id=,quotation,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,status=no,width=800,height=600');
});

Comment: Thank you very much